# What does this code from Eloquent JS Chapter 5 do?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have hard time understanding the first part of the code. I don't understand what we're after with the `combine` function. Also what does `thisOneCounts` do? Really, anything I haven't commented over I don't understand.

```
//count the ancestors over 70
function countAncestors(person, test) {
    //supposed to combine parents recursively
    function combine(person, fromMother, fromFather) {
        //stores people over 70
        var thisOneCounts = test(person);
        //if the person passed the `test` (>70), then 1 is included
        return fromMother + fromFather + (thisOneCounts ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return reduceAncestors(person, combine, 0);
}

//find the percentage of known ancestors, who lived > 70 years
function longLivingPercentage(person) {
    var all = countAncestors(person, function(person) {
        return true;
    });
    var longLiving = countAncestors(person, function(person) {
        //lifespan
        return (person.died - person.born) >= 70;
    });
    //percentage of >70
    return longLiving / all;
}
console.log(longLivingPercentage(byName["Emile Haverbeke"]));
// → 0.145
```

The `reduceAncestors` function:

```
function reduceAncestors(person, f, defaultValue) {
  function valueFor(person) {
    if (person == null)
      return defaultValue;
    else
      return f(person, valueFor(byName[person.mother]),
                       valueFor(byName[person.father]));
  }
  return valueFor(person);
}
```

Comment: I would insist please add better title to your question.

Comment: It would help if we could also see `reduceAncestors()`

Comment: What should the title be?

Comment: The title should relate to the specific problem you're having.

Comment: Where is this book coming from, why are we suddenly getting so many questions from it, and why does the code in it kinda suck?

Comment: @ryan To answer the middle question: because half of the members on this site are reading it, and the other half are telling people to read it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a lot going on here, but to break it down:

`countAncestors` returns the number of ancestors of `person` (including the person themself) that match the criteria in a provided test function (`test`)

`longLivingPercentage` first uses the `countAncestors` function to count *all* ancestors of the specified person (by using a test that always returns `true`), and then uses it again to count all ancestors of the specified person that died at age 70 or above.

`reduceAncestors` fans out through the family tree by recursively seeking out each parent and then using the provided function `f` (which in this case is `combine`) to merge together the results.

`combine`, as stated above, is used to merge the values recursively obtained by `reduceAncestors`. It adds together the total number of matched ancestors for the current person's father and mother, and then adds in the current person to that total if they match the test.

Presuming a family tree where the initial person (G) passed in had exactly one father and mother (E and F), and two grandparents on each side (A, B, C, and D), and a test that always returns true, the recursive calls to `combine` would look like this:

```
combine(A,0,0) = 1   combine(B,0,0) = 1   combine(C,0,0) = 1   combine(D,0,0) = 1
       |                    |                    |                   |
       ----------------------                    ---------------------
                |                                          |
        combine(E,1,1) = 3                         combine(F,1,1) = 3
                |                                          |
                --------------------------------------------
                                     |
                             combine(G, 3, 3) = 7
```